# How to create a DataRelation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I get an error when creating a datarelation - 'DataRelation does not contain a constuctor that takes 3 arguments. Where am I going wrong.

```
DataColumn dcParent = ds.Tables["Directors"].Columns["did"];
DataColumn dcChild = ds.Tables["Movies"].Columns["did"];

//Error here
DataRelation MovieDirectors = new DataRelation("dr1", dcParent, dcChild);
```

Comment: You are correct, so the problem must be somthing else. I suspect `DataRelation` is not the `System.Data.DataRelation`. Make sure you got the correct class.

Comment: Thank you AMissico. That worked. But why is it so. All the examples I see just said 'DataRelation'. Is there any other datarelation in some other namespace?

Comment: Yes, you have a namespace conflict. It depends on your references and what namespaces you added through the `using` directive. A "namespace alias" is helpful in these cases or use fully qualified names, see <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx> for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments:

> You are correct, so the problem must be somthing else. I suspect DataRelation is not the System.Data.DataRelation. Make sure you got the correct class. – AMissico
>
> Thank you AMissico. That worked. But why is it so. All the examples I see just said 'DataRelation'. Is there any other datarelation in some other namespace? – Ruby

Yes, you have a namespace conflict. It depends on your references and what namespaces you added through the using directive. A "namespace alias" is helpful in these cases or use fully qualified names, see [Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DataRelation MovieDirectors = new DataRelation("dr1", dcParent, dcChild,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intitialzing a DataRelation is quite simple; you can use the basic constructor. In your case, something like:

```
DataRelation moviedirector = new DataRelation("dr1", ds.Tables["Directors"].Columns["did"], ds.Tables["Movies"].Columns["did"];);

ds.Relations.Add(moviedirector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ds.Relations.Add(MovieDirectors);
```